# Problem executing some PHP data after 1.5 seconds

Tags: php, delay

I have some PHP code whereby I post data to an API and get some response data. When a user pays the response status from the API should change. I am trying to delay the execution of PHP code and wait for 15 seconds before getting the payment status from the API which is not working as expected.. I have no idea how to do that in PHP or rather Laravel Queues since am using Laravel 5.4

~ Kindly assist?

```
 $data = array(
            'payment_reference' => $checkID,
            'payment_type' => $type
        );

        //Post request to an API and get the status and store in a variable
        $paySt = $this->global_Curl($data, 'api/payment/status')->data;

        sleep(15);

        //Second call to the API after sleep to check if status has changed
       $payStat = $this->global_Curl($data, 'api/payment/status')->data;

        if($payStat->status === '1'){
             return 'true';   
        }
```

Comment: Do you re-fetch the data after the `sleep()` to see if it has updated?

Comment: What does not work? Does the code fail? Do you get errors? or do you mean that 4 seconds is not enough for the status to change to 1

Comment: How are you populating `$payStat`? If it's set prior to calling `sleep()` the delay isn't going to do anything. You likely need a second call to whatever service is processing your payments.

Comment: I dont think you have shown us enough code for us to do anything other than play 20 questions with you

Comment: your code isn't going to change mid request by just waiting

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [TAKE THE TOUR](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @NigelRen Please check the updated question

Comment: @RiggsFolly Please check the updated question

Comment: @ErikGiberti Please check updated question

Answer (score 0):

`sleep()` function is used to delay the current execution

check the link

https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_misc_sleep

In your case, you need to again call the payment api after 4-5 sec delay

For Example:

```
#Payment process hit code

#sleep(4); //delay/wait for 4 second

#Again run code to check the payment status.
```